# Factory canned grape juice

Tags: food-safety

Is grape juice ok to drink in an unopened can with the expiration date 5 years ago. It has also been refrigerated though unopened.

Comment: Anecdotally - I once opened a can of condensed milk that was at least 18 years old. It had set to a jelly & the sugar was in large crystals... but it hadn't 'gone off'. We tasted it it for a dare [we were young & foolish] but it actually tasted fine. We did throw it away of course, as it wasn't exactly pourable any more.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the can is undamaged, and in good condition, it is safe.  Expiration dates are typically used to define a period of time when the product is of the best quality, rather than to define safety.  Since this was very likely a pasteurized product, it most certainly did not turn into wine or vinegar. It might not taste great, but if the can remained sealed it will not be unsafe either.

Answer (score 0):

It might not kill you, but chances are it'll be vile.  Why do this to yourself?

Answer (score -1):

5 years is a long, long time.

At best it turned into wine (lol), at worse into vinegar!

I would discard it.